# How to read TIMESTAMPTZ column value in sesson timezone which is set by SET TIMEZONE query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to read a timestamptz data with java jdbc.

When i set session timezone (connection timezone) on postgresql, i expect to read all timestamptz columns in given timezone of the session. When i read resultset with getString() method it returns expected timestamptz value, but getTimestamp() method returns the date in default timezone of jvm.

Here is sample code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tztestdb", "postgres", "123456");

        Statement setTZ = connection.createStatement();
        setTZ.execute("SET timezone='UTC'");
        //setTZ.execute("SET timezone='Europe/Istanbul'");

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT datetimetzcol,datetimecol FROM TZTEST");

        ResultSetMetaData jMetadata = rs.getMetaData();
        int ColumnType = jMetadata.getColumnType(1);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("STRING: " + rs.getString(1) + " TYPE ->" + ColumnType);
            System.out.println("TIME S: " + rs.getTimestamp(1) + " TYPE ->" + ColumnType);
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is the output :

> STRING: 2020-01-01 07:00:00+00 TYPE ->93
>
> TIME S: 2020-01-01 10:00:00.0 TYPE ->93

My database table contains two columns first one is a timestamptz the secondone is timestamp. When i test a similar code in mysql retunrs identical dates unlike postgresql.

Additionally, when i read timestamptz column with a timezone information, nothing changes. Here is my additonal row:

```
System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp(1, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))));
```

and output is same:

> 2020-01-01 10:00:00.0

My expected value is:

> 2020-01-01 07:00:00.0

Is there a solution to avoid reading timestamptz column in jvm's default timezone. I just want to read data in session's timezone which i set it with SET TIMEZONE query.

Comment: Use `getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class)` stop using `java.sql.Timestamp` (btw: the `Cass.forName()` hasn't been necessary to load a driver for a long time)

Comment: getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class) always returns UTC time. When i uncomment the line -> setTZ.execute("SET timezone='Europe/Istanbul'"); It still returns UTC.  I don't want to make an timezone operation on returning date.

Comment: You want a conversion from UTC to your time zone to happen, but you don’t want to perform such a conversion — did I understand that correctly?